# Google Analytic Authentication by using Auth2.x

Tags: analytics

I was develop and application, which can produce number of associated table if for a user and when user select appropriate client he can view report based on user id, password and table id.

Now, google change authentication process and introduce Auth2.x process to authenticate a user.

Is there any body who can help me regarding this problem, this will be a great help.

I am a .net developer so any help in dotnet will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide. Look at section "Create a Project in the Google APIs Console" it will walk you through the whole process. This is what I used and it helped.